# How can I model this database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working in a web aplication to evaluate workers. In a php form I add the name of the worker and there are 10 questions. Each question has options (a, b, c, d).
Example:

1. quality of work.

   - a) excellent
   - b) good
   - c) bad
   - d) too bad
2. professional knowledge.

   - a) excellent knowledge
   - b) is ok
   - c) man has little knowledge
   - d) dont know nothing

My problem is that I can not correctly model the MYSQL database. I planned on making a table for questions and one for answers and one for the area of the worker. But I can not do it.
Please could help me model this base?
I think they should be only those tables: "tbl_worker", "tbl_alternative", "tbl_question", "tbl_answer".

[image: Model]

Comment: Got any code/what have you tried(more in depth)?

Comment: A table for questions and a table for answers sound good. You'll also want a table for responses (so you can associate multiple questions that have been answered, and by who) and one for surveys (so you can associate multiple questions to ask). I am not sure what "But I can not view them" is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this were me i would use the following tables and fields.

```
tbl_worker
    id
    name

tbl_questions
    id
    question

tbl_question_answer
    id
    question_id
    answer

tbl_report
    id
    worker_id 

tbl_worker_report
    id
    report_id
    question_answer_id
```

Put all of your questions in the questions table then you join them together with the answers using a Many(answers)ToOne(question) relationship.

Then you create a new report setting the worker id. Then itterate through all the questions and save, the answer, and the report_id into the tbl_worker_report table.

Then you can view the results by getting all of the report by looking for all rows that have the report id of the report you want to view. and because your answer also reference the question you can get that too if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the things you have.  You have a "Worker", a "Question" which has "Possible Answers", then you could possibly have "Questions a Worker Answered" (which would allow you to have different questions for different workers but not force you to)

Worker would have a primary key + what data you collect about the worker.
Question would have a primary key + what data you collect about the question.
Possible Answers would have a primary key + a foreign key to Question + what data you collect for answers to questions
Questions a Worker Answered would have a primary key + a foreign key to the Question + a foreign key to the Possible Answer + a foreign key to the Worker + any other data you need to collect.

Example

```
Worker
+id : int
+name : string

Question
+id : int
+text : string

PossibleAnswer
+id : int
+question_id : int
+text : string

AnsweredQuestion
+id : int
+question_id : int
+possibleanswer_id : int
+worker_id : int
+time_answered : datetime
```